# Как упростить логику? Регулярки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить

1. Длину и вывести ошибку что длина не должна превышать 10 цифр начиная с кода оператора
2. какая цифра стоит после 8 или 7.Вывести что оператор должен начинаться с цифры 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 если после 7 и 8 стоит другая цифра

   ```
   const isValidMobile = value => {
       const phoneMobile = /^[78]{0,1}[345689]/;


     //value приходит в виде +790.... или в виде 890...
     const isNotFullSevenPhoneInput =
      /^\+7/.test(value) && value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '').length < 12;
    const isNotFullEightPhoneInput =
   /^8/.test(value) && value.length < 11;

    if (isNotFullSevenPhoneInput || isNotFullEightPhoneInput ) {
       return phoneError.lengthError
     }


    const startWithCorrectSymbol =
       (/^8/.test(value) && phoneMobile.test(value))
       || ( /^\+7/.test(value) &&  
   phoneMobile.test(value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ''))) ;

    if (!startWithCorrectSymbol) {
       return phoneError.operatorError;
    }

     return '';
   ```

   };

Comment: По ощущениям вы проверяете по нескольку раз одно и то же ... чего в конечном итоге вы пытаетесь добиться то? (какие значения должна пропускать валидация)

Comment: [.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Есть два вида номера телефона
+790312222
и вида 89022222

Comment: нужно проверить
1. Длину и вывести ошибку что длина не должна превыщать 11 символов
2. Вывести что оператор должен начинаться с цифры 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
если после 7 и 8 стоит другая

Comment: дописал в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const phoneError = {
  operatorError: 'Ошибка оператора',
  lengthError: 'Ошибка длины'
};

const isValidMobile = value => {
  const match = value.match(/^\+?(\d+)/);
  // Обе проверки "от противного", то есть мы ищем не соответствие ожидаемому, а несоответствие
  return !/^(?:\+7|8)[345689]/.test(value) // Проверяем, что НЕ начинается с ("+7" или "8", а следом идет одно из чисел `[345689]`)
    ? phoneError.operatorError // если это так, то возвращаем `phoneError.operatorError`
    : match && match[1].length > 11 // Проверяем, что не считая возможно стоящего в начале "+" друг за другом идут числа (надо убедиться, что они вообще заматчились, иначе match[1] выдаст ошибку) и их больше 11
      ? phoneError.lengthError // если это так, то возвращаем `phoneError.lengthError`
      : '';
};
    
console.log(isValidMobile('+790312222'));
console.log(isValidMobile('+720312222'));
console.log(isValidMobile('+7903122222222'));
console.log(isValidMobile('89022222'));
console.log(isValidMobile('81022222'));
console.log(isValidMobile('890222222222'));
```

По хорошему бы конечно ещё пару проверок добавить, но ошибок под несоответствие нет (как и условий в задаче), будем считать, что оно и не надо.